# VueX update state from action with commit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I'm pretty new to Vuex, can someone tell me why I can't access the state from an action, modify it, and then commit it? I make a "deep" copy of the state array before I change it. What is the alternative best practice way of doing this?

This is my action:

```
[Action.UPDATE_CHERRYPICK_SIZE] ({ state, commit }, { recipe, size }) {
    var shoppinglist = [...state.shoppinglist]
    var cp = shoppinglist.find(v => v.recipe.id === recipe.id)
    cp.size = size
    commit(Mutation.SET_SHOPPINGLIST, shoppinglist)
}
```

Comment: in this example the copy is shallow !?

Comment: I have also tried to do it like .. var shoppinglist = state.shoppinglist.slice()  .. with the same result.

Comment: slice is also shallow - as long as you mutate deeper than you copy you trigger the setter warning

Comment: Uh, how to do it then ? ;)

Comment: what can work on a shallow copy is to `item.splice(item.findindex, 1, newlyCreatedMutatedItem)` but its only my jsut in head compiler - so untested

Comment: var shoppinglist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.shoppinglist))  did the job, but seams like a nasty hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only make changes to state in mutations. (That's why it's called mutations.) You don't need to clone the list.  Create a mutation for setting `cp` size:

```
SET_CP_SIZE(state, { cp, size }) {
  cp.size = size;
}
```

And in your action:

```
[Action.UPDATE_CHERRYPICK_SIZE] ({ state, commit }, { recipe, size }) {
  var cp = state.shoppinglist.find(v => v.recipe.id === recipe.id)
  commit(Mutation.SET_CP_SIZE, { cp, size })
}
```

This way doesn't use `state` in the mutation directly, but that's fine.  Instead you are setting `cp` which is an item of some state array.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to write a mutation to update the state. In the SET_SHOPPINGLIST mutation, you can access the state and set values.

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing
>   a mutation. Vuex mutations are very similar to events: each mutation
>   has a string type and a handler. The handler function is where we
>   perform actual state modifications, and it will receive the state as
>   the first argument:

Please refer to [the link](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) to see the code examples.